# Google Ads API - get customerId from e-mail address

Tags: php, laravel, google-ads-api

I am trying to create a web application (backend is in PHP / Laravel), with this functionality

1. user ads a valid gmail address
2. system checks if the address is valid and if such a address is assigned to a Google Ads Account
3. if true, system should "somehow" retrieve the customerId of the google ads account, or all of them if there are more than one accessible from the address
4. system checks if the ads account is an MCC account
   step
5. if so, system should list all of the customers the mcc account is "handling"
   ...

My question is - how do I do step 3?

The "input" data I have is the e-mail address, at this point I already know that it's valid, and the account has already given permission to my application to access google ads, I have everything properly configured, but

I have no clue HOW to do it. The official API documentation is not very helpful, just like the official PHP library which I'm using, it assumes that I KNOW the customerId (or the loginCustomerId in the case of MCC accounts).

Any clue how could I do it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/socialite

Comment: Thanks for your response Bohdan Petrenko, but I don't understand how can socialite help me in this case - it is a package for login / authentication, right? After checking the methods it can return the id, nickname, name, email and avatar for the google account, and not the ads account customers, or am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: if i understand you right, u need token with google ad scopes, with his help u can make validation and other moves

Comment: Sorry, I should probably specify it better - I don't need to get the token with ad scopes, I have it already. My problem is that I don't know how to get the customer id (or list of customer ids) of the affected google ads account

Comment: sorry, I never work with google ads api, so only what i can, its pushup your question. good luck